# Can WinPcap send and get Ethernet header over one NIC card?

Tags: networking, winpcap

I'm studying with WinPcap API on one computer, as you predict I have one NIC card and I couldn't send and get Ethernet header on one NIC card.

Can you please inform me whether WinPcap can send and get Ethernet header over one NIC card to determine whether it is my fault or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after a bit try I sent and got an ethernet header over a NIC card by using WinPcap

**EDIT:**

If you follow [this tutorial](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_41/html/group__wpcap__tut.html) you can do it without any problem. This tutorial completely shows the steps about sending packets and capturing them.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **how** you managed to do this.

Comment: Better, but no cigar. [This help article](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) says "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline**" [emphasis mine]. This is the reason I won't upvote your answer (yet); I did upvote the question though.